# Apple Mach-O Linker Error, Simulator and Target

Tags: linker, ios-simulator

I have Apple Mach-O Linker Error, and I think these questions are related to that.

1. Can we test the app using iOS simulator, or we must enroll in Apple
   Dev Program to test it on an iDevice?
2. Is it important the target to be iOS6 or we can use iOS7?
3. How can we remove Apple Mach-O Linker errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Sphero is not working on the simulator.